# Why override select-payment-method.js in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need reason for why override `Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method` during add `custom total item` in Magento 2? Please explain it?

Answer (score 0):

If you will not override the Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method and you will customize that file code in core file It will work but after upgrading the Magento all core files will override by new Magento core files and you custom code will be removed. So you need to override the core file during add custom.

Comment: Ok banvari la, I know about this but i want what's action perform inside this js?